# Java Recursive Binomial Coeffecients using Linked Lists

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, binomial-coefficients

There is a challenge problem in my compsci UIL class to use tail recursion to get a list of binomial coefficients for a given number . I think I am pretty close but I am having a hard time with base cases.

Following is my Code :

```
 public static Cons binomial(int n) 
    {
        return binomialb(n, null, 1);

    }
public static Cons binomialb(int n, Cons last, int power)
{

    if(n == power || n < 0)
    {
        return cons(1, null);
    }   
    else if(last == null)
    {
        last = cons(1, cons(1, null));
        return binomialb(n-1, last, power);
    }
    else
    { 
        Cons lst = cons(1, null);
        while(rest(last)!=null)
        {
        lst = cons((Integer)first(last)+(Integer)first(rest(last)), lst);
            last = rest(last);
        }
        return binomialb(n-1,lst,power);
    }

}
```

Right now I just get a list of (1).....

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive call is always `binomialb(n-1,something,power)`, so the only things that change are the first parameter, `n`, and the list. Your initial call has `power = 1`, so that will remain forever so. Now your first condition is

```
if (n == power || n < 0) { 
    return cons(1,null);
}
```

If you call it with `n > 1` initially, the calls become `binomialb(n-k,...,1)` for `k = 1, ..., n-1`. Finally the call is `binomialb(1,lotsOfWastedWork,1)` which will happily return `cons(1,null)`. If you initially call it with `n < 1`, the `n < 0` will make it return the same after at most one recursive call, `n = 1` immediately returns `cons(1,null)`.

Whenever `last` is not null in a call, you should use it.